# Smooth Contour Plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot smooth contour plot from X Y Z matrix.

```
sf = fit([X Y] Z, 'poly23');
plot(sf);
```

I have not enought smooth curve..
What I need?

[image]

Comment: what is your X Y and Z? it would help more if we have an example of the data you are trying to plot :)

Comment: it's a column of data. they are too big to attach :(
Z is an intensity at the point (X,Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions such as [griddata](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) and [csaps](http://au.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csaps.html). Together they will lead you to the result as smooth as you wish. The first function adds additional points to your data matrix set. The second one makes the result smoother. The example of the code is below. In the example smoothing is done first in X direction and then in Y direction. Try to play around with the `resolution` and `smoothing_parameter` (the current set of these parameters should be OK though).

```
x = min_x:step_x:max_x;
y = min_y:step_y:max_y;
resolution = 10;

xg = min_x:(step_x/resolution):max_x;
yg = min_y:(step_y/resolution):max_y;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
[XG,YG] = meshgrid(xg,yg);    


smoothing_parameter = 0.02;
fitted = griddata(X,Y,Z,XG,YG,'cubic');
fitted_smoothed_x = csaps(xg,fitted,smoothing_parameter,xg);
fitted_smoothed_xy = csaps(yg,fitted_smoothed_x',smoothing_parameter,yg);

surf(XG,YG,fitted_smoothed_xy');
```

**EDIT:** If you want to get just a contour plot, you can do, for example, as presented below. As I don't have the real data, I will use build-in function [`peaks`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/peaks.html?searchHighlight=peaks) to generate some.

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
figure
surfc(X,Y,Z)
view([0 90])
zlim([-10 -8])
```

Here you just look at your contour plot from above being below the surface.

Comment: Thanks!
hp=surfc(...);set(hp(2), 'ShowText', 'on')

Comment: But I need contour plot.

Comment: how apply csaps to contour plot?

Comment: Check the "EDIT" section in my answer.

Comment: The smooth surface sometimes doesn't have a smooth contour.

Comment: Did u try to play around with the parameters?